# Get the process id of the app, which called the service

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an service in automator, which is binded to the Safari ,no input option.

Now is there any way for the service in automator to get the process id of the Safari, which called it ?

New to applescript and automator. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: I asked almost the same question and gave my answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145074/how-do-i-determine-which-application-launched-automator-service). If you are running 10.6.8 it may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As you launch the service from Safari, the application will be the one in the foreground.

You can use this Applescript in the "`Run AppleScript`" action.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set x to first process whose its frontmost is true and name is "Safari"
    return unix id of x
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if many Safari runs? So thats my question to get the process id of the Safari ( many safari will run) which called the service?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. It works. But the problem is the safari is driven by scripts, so its not mandatory that it should be in foreground. Any idea how do I get the pid now? Without foreground things?

Comment: Without foreground things, it's possible but very complicated. The best place is in the script that launches Safari. But as I have no details about the whole process, it is impossible to give a correct answer.

Comment: Java launches the safari. Basically its an Selenium suite. There is no way in Selenium java to get the pid. Thats my worry. Without foreground things, can you say me how things can be done?

Comment: Depending on your version of OS, [my related question/answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145074/55365) may be what you are after.